# При установки 1с при помощи SLS файла не ставиться служба

Tags: saltstack

Есть SLS файл собственного написания. Планируется использовать для установки 1С на удаленных точках. На сервера в точках нужно ставить сервер на кассы не нужно, условия описаны. Проблема в том что при установки на машину где должен стоять сервер 1С не создается служба, консоль администрирования ставиться, ragent.exe тоже есть по пути установки, нет только службы.
Пример SLS файла.

```
1c_32:
  {% for version in ['8.3.12.1714',
                     '8.3.12.1685',
                     '8.3.10.2667',
                     '8.3.10.2252',
                     '8.3.8.2137',
                     '8.3.6.2152',
                     '8.2.19.83'] %}
  {% if grains['windowsdomain'] == 'WORKGROUP' %}
  {% set install_location = 'APTEKA' %}
  {% else %}
  {% set install_location = 'srv-fs' %} 
  {% endif %}
  '{{ version }}':
    full_name: '1C:Предприятие 8 ({{ version }})'
    installer: '//{{ install_location }}/install/1c/{{ version }}/windows/x32/1CEnterprise 8.msi'
  {% if grains['host'] == 'APTEKA' %}
    install_flags: '/lv D:\log.txt /qr  TRANSFORMS=1049ph-2.mst DESIGNERALLCLIENTS=1 SERVER=1 SERVERCLIENT=1 LANGUAGES=RU'
  {% else %}
    install_flags: '/lv D:\log.txt /qr  TRANSFORMS=1049ph-2.mst DESIGNERALLCLIENTS=1 LANGUAGES=RU'
  {% endif %}
    uninstaller: '//{{ install_location }}/install/1c/{{ version }}/windows/x32/1CEnterprise 8.msi'
    uninstall_flags: '/qn /norestart '
    reboot: False
    msiexec: True
  {% endfor %}
```

Если я правильно понял то в итоге формируется строка вида

> "\COMPUTERNAME\install\1c\VRSION\windows\x32\1CEnterprise 8.msi" /lv D:\log.txt /qr  TRANSFORMS=1049ph-2.mst DESIGNERALLCLIENTS=1 THINCLIENTFILE=0 THINCLIENT=0 WEBSERVEREXT=0 SERVER=1 CONFREPOSSERVER=0 CONVERTER77=0 SERVERCLIENT=1 LANGUAGES=RU

Так вот если эту же строку выполнить из командной строки то все ставиться как надо включая службу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в самом файле 1049ph, при его редактировании была допущена ошибка, а именно было отключена установка службы. И в соответствии с параметрами в 1049ph все ставилось корректно. После изменения файла все стало работать как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Так у Вас в sls-файле и не указаны ключи THINCLIENTFILE=0 THINCLIENT=0 WEBSERVEREXT=0 CONFREPOSSERVER=0 CONVERTER77=0, так, как Вы делаете это из командной строки.

Вот кусок заведомо рабочего sls-файла для установки клиента. НЕ сервера. В Вашем случае просто проставьте 1 возле "серверных" ключей и, соответственно, 0 возле параметров, отвечающих за установку клиента:

```
    {% set instflags = '' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + '/qn ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'TRANSFORMS=adminstallrelogon.mst;1049.mst ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'DESIGNERALLCLIENTS=1 ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'THICKCLIENT=1 ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'THINCLIENTFILE=1 ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'THINCLIENT=1 ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'WEBSERVEREXT=0 ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'SERVER=0 ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'CONFREPOSSERVER=0 ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'CONVERTER77=0 ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'SERVERCLIENT=0 ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'LANGUAGES=RU,UK ' %}
    {% set instflags = instflags + 'DEFLANGUAGE=RU ' %}
```

Comment: ключи THINCLIENTFILE=0 THINCLIENT=0 WEBSERVEREXT=0 CONFREPOSSERVER=0 CONVERTER77=0 не указываются явно так-как по умолчанию они как раз и принимают значения 0. Я не увидел смысла их указывать явно когда это ничего не изменит. Но благодарю за пример SLS файла.